# Run MDX query on SSAS server via JMeter

Tags: load-testing

I have to connect Jmeter tool with SSAS cubes ( SQL Server Analysis Services ). So I can execute MDX query and check the performance and load testing of SSAS cube.

Please some one guide me how can I setup connection with SSAS Cube and which driver I need to use (as available with JMeter 5.0).

Please let me know , Is this possible to connect JMeter with SSAS Cube or not? If Yes, please guide me how to do this with example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following options:

1. Use [olap4j driver](http://www.olap4j.org/) from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) from [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), the example code can be found at [olap4j github page](https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j#writing-a-simple-program). You will need to [Configure XML/A HTTP Access to Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=asallproducts-allversions) beforehand
2. There is [SQL Analysis Services JDBC Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/ssas/jdbc/) which can be used along with [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response @Dmitri. I do have query on the same i.e. SQL Analysis Services JDBC Driver is not getting downloaded as jar so how to use it in jmeter. Secondly, what should be the JDBC Driver class used in configurations